# How to get only a text corresponding to the id from MySQL and store it as a variable in PHP

Tags: php, mysql, database, mysqli, database-connection

I'm a begginer to PHP and I want to know how can I fetch some text from the corresponding ID and store it as a variable in PHP.

The table is like

```
ID----NAME----ACCOUNT----PASSWORD
1----name1----accont1----password2
2----name2----accont2----password2
3----name3----accont3----password3
```

Now if I want to get the account2 as text and save it in an variable (say acc2) then what should I do. Assuming that I have connection information in connect.php. 
Edit: I want to select the account2 using the ID like from ID 2 select account.

Thanks In Advance!!!

Comment: please show what you have written up to now.

Comment: Oh! In so sorry I have not yet written anything I'm analysing how ti do that for my school project and I'm just connecting the dots I just learnt how to create MySQL quries and how to connect to db please help.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How can I get an unknown username given an ID?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60741213/how-can-i-get-an-unknown-username-given-an-id)

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please review [How do I ask a good question](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Stack Overflow is not a coding service. You are expected to do some research on your issue and make a good attempt to write the code yourself before posting. If you get stuck on something specific, come back and include a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) and a summary of what you tried, and we will try to help.

Comment: @FluffyKitten Sure I'll ask my further questions correctly. Thanks!!!

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Assuming you use MySQL, the table is named users and you are using PDO, this would get what you need:

```
$stmt = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM users WHERE ID = 2");
$row = $stmt->fetch()
$account = $row['ACCOUNT']
```

Comment: I'm sorry I can't understand the code can you please tell me with the example that I have given

Comment: BTW. What is pdo

Comment: It's the recommended way to connect to a MySQL database in PHP. See https://www.php.net/manual/ro/book.pdo.php ; Without knowing how you connect to the database and what your table name is , I can't help much more than this.

Comment: Yes that's how I connect.

Comment: Then you just need to do that, assuming your PDO connection handler is in scope and your table is named users

Comment: I connected as mentioned here. "PHP MySQL Connect to database" https://www.w3schools.com/php/php_mysql_connect.asp

Comment: Ok you have now edited that but I want to select it from the ID like in ID 2 select account

Comment: You just change the WHERE from ACCOUNT to ID and the values correspondingly.

Comment: Ok now the ID 2 is selected but how to select account2 through that

Comment: Thank you so much will try.